# insert data from select query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert data from existing variable and selected column from another table

here is my code

```
$jobtitle=$_POST['jobtitle'];
$jobdescription=$_POST['jobdescription'];
$requirements=$_POST['requirements'];
$resume=$_POST['resume'];
$expyears=$_POST['expyears'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
$useremail=$_SESSION['email'];

$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO career (jobtitle, jobdescription, requirements, expyears, resume, useremail, resname) VALUES ('$jobtitle','$jobdescription','$requirements','$expyears','$resume','$useremail', SELECT resname FROM restaurant WHERE useremail='$useremail')");
```

but the above code does not give any result to my database

is there any solution for this problem?

thanks

Comment: Are you 110% sure that the values are actually set? You can never be sure without [checking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: Did you use `mysql_connect` to connect to your database? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: You don't show a connection to the database or any error checking.

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments @DarkBee.

Comment: [generic SQL injection warning]

Comment: @Jay I don't want that comment treated as valid  code cause it's plain bad coding

Comment: Then why post it without any qualification @DarkBee? Not sure I understand.

Comment: George already did that now :)

Comment: I hope for your sake this code is nowhere near a production server. Please, stop writing SQL code this awful. This is completely reckless and full of severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Note that you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) since it is a deprecated library. Think about making the move to `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Having said that, your query is incorrect. You can't use `VALUES()` and a selection together in an `INSERT` statement. You should instead, select the string literals you are trying to insert along with the one value you'd like to select.

Try the following instead:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO career (jobtitle, jobdescription, requirements, expyears, resume, useremail, resname)
    SELECT '$jobtitle','$jobdescription','$requirements','$expyears','$resume','$useremail', resname
    FROM restaurant 
      WHERE useremail='$useremail'
";
```

Comment: There is no `VALUES` keyword, just a selection.

Comment: So explain that, instead of just posting potentially correct (but vulnerable to SQL injection) code without telling teh OP why this is right.

Comment: That is totally wrong because INSERT does not accept WHERE. Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: @Begueradj No, but `SELECT` does.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I made a clear warning prior to answering, there's not a lot else for me to do as far as that is concerned. Since this issue is directly MySQL based and not actually anything to do with PHP, I see no reason not to continue answering.

Comment: @Begueradj That is totally wrong becuase this query is perfectly correct.

Comment: If you really want to encourage using placeholders, which is a great idea, provide answers using them. This has just weaponized a previously non-functional query. If the person asking the question insists on playing with fire, they can be responsible for adding the SQL injections themselves.